# Как убрать запрос авторизации при открытии страницы?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

При открытии главной страницы, которая ссылается на зарегистрированный `router`:

```
from rest_framework import routers
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', coreviews.UserViewSet)
url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

браузер сам запрашивает авторизацию вида

[image: Запрос авторизации].

Как убрать это?

Ведь при отмене всё равно выдаётся сообщение в rest:

```
"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

Comment: Что вы хотите получить в итоге? Возможность использовать API без какой либо  авторизации или возможность получить доспуп без авторизации тоько к списку методов (к главной странице)?

Comment: @KirillErmolov , я хочу сделать так, чтобы браузер не показывал это "своё" окно с запросом авторизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В *Django rest framework* есть большое количество способов [аутентификации](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

Насколько я могу судить у вас показывается окно авторизации потому что вы используется аутентификацию [BasicAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication). Для этого типа аутентификации вышеупомянутое окно это нормальное поведение.

Вы можете указать один способ аутентификации или несколько, в таком случае  *Django rest framework* будет пытаться применить указанные способы последовательно, до первого успешного.

Для того чтобы убрать окно либо удалите способ аутентификации *BasicAuthentication* либо добавьте перед ним какой-то другой способ аутентификации, например [SessionAuthentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication)

Сделать это можно в настройках:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    )
}
```

тогда эти настройки применятся ко всем api методам.

Или отдельно для каждой вьюхи:

```
class UserViewSet(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
```